# Is s-bgp deployed and used?

Tags: bgp

Is s-bgp actually deployed/present on routers, or is it just an accademic protocol?

Where is bgp security moving to (if it is moving in any particular way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen it used in professional networks (which does not mean it isn't used anywhere). BGP security is a bit of a broad subject, but the one feature which has been gaining some traction recently is route validation using RPKI.

Answer (score 3):

I did a search on both Cisco and Juniper's sites for S-BGP configurations.  I didn't find any, which leads me to conclude that it is not a protocol in wide use.